# Como eliminar consulta duplicada y contarlas en mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una gran duda. Estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta en mi bd

`SELECT modulos.cursoModulo, cursos.* FROM modulos 
    RIGHT JOIN cursos ON cursoModulo = idCurso`
 
El resultado lo listo en una tabla y se muestra el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo desde PHP hacer que en vez de mostrarme 2 veces el mismo curso, me sume las veces que se repite en la columna "Cantidad de secciones" ?? Así es como estoy listando la consulta en una tabla

```
 while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta_cursos)) { 
                    $idCurso = $res['idCurso'];
                    $estadoCurso = 'N/A';
                    $cantidadModulos = 0;
                    if($res['isActiveCurso']  == 0){
                        $estadoCurso = '<i class="fas fa-times-circle rojo"></i> NO';
                    }else{
                        $estadoCurso = '<i class="fas fa-check-circle verde"></i> SI';
                    }
                    if($res['cursoModulo']  == $idCurso){
                        $cantidadModulos++;
                    }
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['idCurso']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['nombreCurso']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['areaCurso']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$cantidadModulos."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$estadoCurso."</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                            echo "<div class='btn-group'>";
                                echo "<a href=\"editCursos.php?idCurso =$res[idCurso]\" title='Editar' class='btn btn-outline-warning'><i class='fas fa-user-edit'></i></a>";
                                if($res['isActiveCurso'] == 1){
                                    echo "<a href=\"deleteCurso.php?idCurso=$res[idCurso]&status=1\" title='Eliminar' class='btn btn-outline-danger'><i class='fas fa-user-times'></i></a>";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<a href=\"deleteCurso.php?idCurso=$res[idCurso]&status=0\" title='Activar' class='btn btn-outline-success'><i class='fas fa-user-check'></i></a>";
                                }

                            echo "</div>";
                        echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";   
                }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Para este caso lo correcto sería **optimizar** la consulta misma, pues no es necesario traer filas repetidas cuando no las necesitas. Si escribes algo así más o menos: `SELECT modulos.cursoModulo, cursos.idCurso, cursos.nombreCurso, cursos.areaCurso, curso.isActiveCurso, COUNT(modulos.cursoModulo)  totalSesiones FROM modulos 
    RIGHT JOIN cursos ON cursoModulo = idCurso GROUP BY cursos.idCurso` La cuestión clave aquí es el `COUNT` combinado con el `GROUP BY`, que agrupará las filas de forma única por ese grupo, trayendo una sola fila en los resultados, que es lo correcto...

Comment: ... Luego, para saber el total de sesiones sólo tienes que buscarlo en `$res['totalSesiones']` que fue el alias que se le dio a la columna que hace el conteo. Quizá el `GROUP BY` podría ser distinto, dependiendo de cómo estés implementando el modelo de datos. No sé si hay debas poner otra columna de la tabla `modulos` también. Lo cierto es que no está optimizada una consulta que trae un montón de filas repetidas. En la pantalla que muestras, aparece lo mismo en las primeras dos filas y ocurrirá eso cada vez que haya registros repetidos. Lo correcto aquí es agrupar con `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias!, tienes toda la razón, eso era lo que buscaba, no había podido visualizar cómo ejecutar una consulta así, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso lo correcto sería optimizar la consulta misma, pues no es necesario traer filas repetidas cuando no las necesitas.

Sería cuestión de escribir algo así más o menos:

```
SELECT 
    modulos.cursoModulo, 
    cursos.idCurso, 
    cursos.nombreCurso, 
    cursos.areaCurso, 
    cursos.isActiveCurso, 
    COUNT(modulos.cursoModulo) totalSesiones 
FROM modulos 
RIGHT JOIN cursos ON cursoModulo = idCurso 
GROUP BY cursos.idCurso ;
```

La cuestión clave aquí es el `COUNT` combinado con el `GROUP BY`, que agrupará las filas de forma única por ese grupo, trayendo una sola fila en los resultados, que es lo correcto.

Luego, para saber el total de sesiones sólo tienes que buscarlo en `$res['totalSesiones']` que fue el alias que se le dio a la columna que hace el conteo.

Quizá el `GROUP BY` podría ser distinto, dependiendo de cómo estés implementando el modelo de datos. No sé si ahí debas poner otra columna de la tabla `modulos` también. Lo cierto es que no está optimizada una consulta que trae un montón de filas repetidas. En la pantalla que muestras, aparece lo mismo en las primeras dos filas y ocurrirá eso cada vez que haya registros repetidos. Lo correcto aquí es agrupar con `GROUP BY`.